Xcode 16.1: 'Cannot Preview in This File' Error on macOS After Adding Firebase SDK
after updating Xcode to Version 16.1, I started a new multiplatform project targeting macOS and iOS. Everything worked fine until I added Firebase SDK 11.4 (using Swift Package Manager). Now, I'm facing an issue where the preview is not possible with "My Mac" after adding Firebase SDK, even with a very simple view like:

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

However, previewing with iPhone or iPad works fine. This is really frustrating. When I run the app on a simulator (Mac, iPhone, or iPad), everything works perfectly.
The error shown is Cannot preview in this file: Failed to launch [AppName] with the following path: /Users/[myname]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[AppName-gemeoxpjlzrshfifmgmqrkcxdeiz/Build/Products/Debug/FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework/FirebaseFirestoreInternal
Run Destination: macOS 15.1.
What I have tried so far:

Cleaned the build folder
Re-installed Firebase SDK

Any insights would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!
